# How can I pass an element to a function from onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create element from code and add as parameter in onclick, element. I tried this: [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wUAGP/1764/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    elementToPass = $('.aaa').children()[0];
    var element = '<div class="ccc" onclick="myFun(' + elementToPass + ')">ccc</div>';
    $('.aaa').append(element);
});
    
myFun = function(){
    console.log('its working');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="aaa">
    <div class="bbb">
        bbb
    </div>
</div>
```

but it caused error;/

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

notice the difference between an element itself and the variable being converted to string while concatenated to other string

i.e. don't perform: `'some text' + elementToPass + 'remaining text'`
because `elementToPass` will become a string rather than the object you intend

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var elementToPass = $('.aaa').children()[0];
    var element = '<div class="ccc" onclick="myFun()">ccc</div>';
    $('.aaa').append(element);

    myFun = function(){
        console.log('its working: ' + elementToPass);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="aaa">
    <div class="bbb">
        bbb
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Had to downvote because you cannot create global variables as you have if you're [using strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), which you should always use. See `First, strict mode makes it impossible to accidentally create global variables. In normal JavaScript mistyping a variable in an assignment creates a new property on the global object and continues to "work" (although future failure is possible: likely, in modern JavaScript)`

Comment: @JuanMendes I have to disagree, as my snippet is closely based on code from original post, including HTML and JS code, and posed issue is sorted out, without introducing any new issue ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I almost agree... But I would still mention that they are using something that is error prone. Why should somebody code like this in 2022! Also, others may try to use your code and get the error I mentioned, the answer should be helpful to the entire community, not just the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Assigning an event handler in code is far better than assigning an inline event handler.  In this particular instance it means you can dynamically pass the element into the function, rather than trying to hardcode a reference in the inline handler.

Change it to this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    elementToPass = $('.aaa').children()[0];
    var element = '<div class="ccc">ccc</div>';

    element.onclick = function() {
        myFun(elementToPass);
    }

    $('.aaa').append(element);
});
```

Comment: Why `element.onclick` instead of `element.addEventHandler`? Please don't use obsolete methods when providing answers. Another way is to use `element.addEventHandler('click', myFun.bind(element, elementToPass))`